# How can I view the whole comment history on a Facebook Wall post?

Tags: facebook, comments

We have a student who has posted a status on Facebook and received some unpleasant comments. The person who has posted the comments has then spammed the comment area, bumping up the comment count to over 3,500 comments. As well as this being probably abuse of Facebook's ToS, is there any way that we can view the post, and all comment on one page?

I've initiated a request for the user to download all their profile information (Facebook will provide this in a .zip) file although I don't know how long this will take to process, and I don't know if this will even work.

Answer (score 3):

On each post there is a timestamp at the lower right, usually after the number of comments and likes on the post.

> [image: where the timestamp is]

Click the timestamp and you'll be taken to a page focussing on just that wall post like so:

> [image: view more when on the page itself]

From there you can keep clicking "View previous comments" to reveal all previous comments.

Comment: This is what we had started to do (found the hint about the permalink in another webapps.se question) but as the comments get loaded 50 at a time (3,700 divided by 50 = 74 clicks) and a slow internet connection means this was going to take *quite a while*. Nevertheless, this is what the student is going to do at home and then e-mail screen captures for us to Deal With. So +1 for you and your drawings.

Comment: Ridiculous that facebook doesn't hightlight comments you have made.  Wonder how many CPU cycles/database queries this wastes daily.